# Optimizing a program for solving ax+by=c with positve integers

Tags: c, optimization, equation, algebra

I am writing a program that for any given positive integers a < b < c will output YES if there is a solution to ax+by=c where x and y are also positive integers (x,y > 0), or NO if there isn't a solution. Keep in mind that I need to work with big numbers.

The approach I take for solving this problem is that I subtract b from c and I check if this number is divisable by a.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    unsigned long long int a, b, c;
    scanf("%I64u %I64u %I64u", &a, &b, &c);
    while(c>=a+b){ //if c becomes less than a+b, than there's no sollution
        c-=b;
        if(c%a==0){
            printf("YES");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("NO");
    return 0;
}
```

is there a more optimised way to find wether ax+by=c has positive sollutions? I tried reading about linear Diophantine equations, but all I found is a way to find integer sollutions (but not positive).

Comment: Is every single variable here constrained to be integer only?

Comment: @shuttle87 Yes, a,b and c are positive integers, and so should be x and y if they exist.

Comment: You should not be saving your spacebar so much, code looks ugly and is less readable.

Comment: The program would be more informative if it output the solution rather than YES.

Comment: OH! I totally read that line as a printf, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

My approach so far.

1. Use [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to find GCD(a, b)
2. There are solutions (in integers) to ax + by = c if and only if GCD(a, b) divides c. No integer solutions means no positive solutions.
3. use [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to solve the [Diophantine equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) and return NO if it gives non-positive solutions.

For comparisons it's hard to find examples that take longer than a second but in deciding on thousands of random equations the performance difference is noticeable.  [This Lecture](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/21-127/lectures/divisibility_5_print.pdf) has a solution for finding the number of positive
solutions to a Linear Diophantine Equation.

```
typedef unsigned long long int BigInt;
int pos_solvable(BigInt a, BigInt b, BigInt c) {
  /* returns 1 if there exists x, y > 0 s.t. ax + by = c
   * where 0 < a < b < c
   * returns 0, otherwise
   */
  BigInt gcd = a, bb = b, temp; 
  while (bb) { /* Euclidean Algorithm */
    temp = bb;
    bb = gcd % bb;
    gcd = temp;
  }
  if (c % gcd) { /* no integer (or positive) solution */
    return 0;
  } else { 
    /* Extended Euclidean Algorithm */
    BigInt s = 0, old_s = 1;
    BigInt t = 1, old_t = 0;
    BigInt r = b / gcd, old_r = a / gcd;

    while (r > 0) {
      BigInt quotient = old_r / r;
      BigInt ds = quotient * s;
      BigInt dt = quotient * t;
      if (ds > old_s || dt > old_t)
        return 0; /* will give non-positive solution */

      temp = s;
      s = old_s - ds;
      old_s = temp;

      temp = t;
      t = old_t - dt;
      old_t = temp; 

      temp = r;
      r = old_r - quotient * r;
      old_r = temp;
    }
    return 1; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a comment but too big for the comment section.

This is posted to help others dig into this problem a little deeper.

OP: Incorporate any of in your post if you like.

What is still needed are some challenging `a,b,c`.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//#define LLF "%I64u"
#define LLF "%llu"

int main(void) {
  unsigned long long int a, b, c, x, y, sum, c0;
  // scanf(LLF LLF LLF, &a, &b, &c);
  c = c0 = ULLONG_MAX;
  b = 10000223;
  a = 10000169;
  y = 0;
  sum = a + b;
  time_t t0 = time(NULL);
  while (c >= sum) { //if c becomes less than a+b, than there's no solution
    c -= b;
    if (c % a == 0) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (c % a == 0) {
    y = (c0 - c) / b;
    x = c / a;
    printf("YES " LLF "*" LLF " + " LLF "*" LLF " = " LLF "\n", a, x, b, y, c);
  } else {
    printf("NO\n");
  }
  time_t t1 = time(NULL);
  printf("time :" LLF "\n", (unsigned long long) (t1 - t0));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
YES 10000169*1844638544065 + 10000223*4688810 = 18446697184563946985
time :0
```